# How do I export video to crop size in Final Cut Pro X?

Tags: video-editor, final-cut-pro-x, export

I started a project with **4K format** and resolution **3840x2160**. Later, I **cropped the clips to a smaller size**. Aspect ratio is still **16:9**, just the resolution is smaller than the original clip.

Now when I send it to the compressor for export, it shows the original 4K size. How do I export it to the actual crop size?

Sorry if it is a silly question, but I started using FCPX this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best if your timeline uses the resolution you want your export in.

Select the Project in your Library and click on "Modify" in the Inspector. Now you can change the resolution for the entire Project.

This will not change the crop of your clips though.